# Feature Selection or PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm having the below Azure Machine Learning question:

> You need to identify which columns are more predictive by using a
> statistical method. Which module should you use?
>
> A. Filter Based Feature Selection
>
> B. Principal Component Analysis

I choose is A but the answer is B. Can someone explain why it is B

Answer (score 1):

PCA is the optimal approximation of a random vector (in N-d space) by linear combination of M (M < N) vectors. Notice that we obtain these vectors by calculating M eigenvectors with largest eigen values. Thus these vectors (features) can (and usually are) a combination of original features.

Filter Based Feature Selection is choosing the best features as they are (not combining them in any way) based on various scores and criteria.

so as you can see, PCA results in better features since it creates better set of features while FBFS merely finds the best subset.

hope that helps ;)

Comment: the question is about which columns are more predictive, what should do is just pick some existing columns which are more important, instead of generating new columns, like you said, PCA is a column-merge thing, and that is why I choose Filter Based Feature Selection

Comment: I see your point. the only explanation I can come up with is that the author meant which columns (of all possible columns, i.e. including the ones we can create) are the best. But it doesn't seem convincing to me either. I'll edit my answer if I came up with a better explanation.